# Add a subview programatically at the bottom of other view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I created a UIView with and added some UIlabels to it through interface builder. I want to add a UIView to this view programatically.

```
 self.view.addSubview(newView)
```

The problem is that the newView hides part of the label I have created with interface builder. How can I make the newView be on the bottom of all subviews?

Comment: can you add some code, whats your interface UIView name

Comment: self.view.insertSubview(bottomView, at: 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you to achieve

```
self.view.insertSubview(newView, at: 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [insertSubview(_:belowSubview:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622598-insertsubview) like this -

```
self.view.insertSubview(newView, belowSubview: yourLabel)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use iOS Layout Anchors:

After
`self.view.addSubview(newView)`

```
newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
newView.topAnchor(equalTo: THE_LOWEST_PLACED_LABEL_IN_VIEW.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
newView.bottomAnchor(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already added this `newView` to `view` use `view.sendSubview(toBack: newView)`, otherwise use `view.insertSubview(newView, at: 0)`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17095516)

Comment: Please add an explanation in your answer (edit it) as to why this answers the question. Code-only answers are not very useful.

Comment: @fedorqui I have edit my answer if I'm wrong please help me let me know why. thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your edit, melvyn! Now the answer is better and probably useful. I would upvote if I knew about the technology to cross check if it is true :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do it, if you use the Interface Builder.

**1)** Select your view in the Interface Builder, and then go:

**Editor -> Arrange -> Send to Back**

**2)** Rearrange all the views in the view list in the left panel (by dragging and dropping one view above another). Look at the the picture.

[image]