# Swift: addSubview is placed on previous view

Tags: swift, nib, addsubview

I use this code for add two view on to parent :

```
let view0 = StarClass.createMyClassView()
parent.addSubview(view0)

let view1 = StarClass.createMyClassView()
parent.addSubview(view1)
```

This code work fine, but `view1` not placed bottom of `view0`

`view1` placed on `view0`

I want add `view1` bottom of `view0`

How i can ?

Comment: use autolayout.

Comment: @AkshaysinghYaduvanshi i want add viewi programmatically

Comment: parent.insertSubview...

Comment: do you mean front&back or top&bottom  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a subview programatically at the bottom of other view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45794199/add-a-subview-programatically-at-the-bottom-of-other-view)

Comment: @Sh_Khan bottom or top. view0 margin top is 0 and i want view1 margin top is 100 ro 0 than view0

Comment: @ElTomato i use parent.insertSubview(view0, at: 0) parent.insertSubview(view1, at: 1) but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using autolayout, see example below.

```
    let view0 = StarClass.createMyClassView()
    view0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // Enables autolayout

    parent.addSubview(view0)

    let view1 = StarClass.createMyClassView()
    view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false 
    parent.addSubview(view1)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        view0.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.leftAnchor), // Set layout for view0
        view0.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.rightAnchor),
        view0.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.topAnchor),
        view0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),

        view1.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.leftAnchor), // Set layout for view1
        view1.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.rightAnchor),
        view1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view0.bottomAnchor), // below view0
        view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        ])
```

Comment: Thank you, best solution for me

Comment: i have another question. how can i use foreach ? sample : for 1...20{ let let view = StarClass.createMyClassView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    parent.addSubview(view) }  . Now, how use NSLayoutConstraint ?!

Comment: You could keep track of the previous added view in a variable, and update it in the loop. Then set the layout in the loop with anchors from the previous view.